# Problem with appending with ndarray and lists. I solved it but couldn't get it as I want

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, nested-lists

**Scenario:** I have a function myfunction() that produces a ndarray always of the form [[0, 5]]. I call myfunction() three times (say) and each time I append the output to an array called nos_indices. It is shown below.

```
nos_indices=myfunction(some argument) #I call once like this first

for loop:
  nos_indices.append( myfunction(some argument)) 

def myfunction(the argument):
    ....
    ranges_ndarray = np.where(absdiff == 1)[0].reshape(-1, 2)   #this gives [[0, 5]]
```

**Problem:** But when I call three times, the append does this `[[0, 5], [[0, 5]], [[0, 5]]]` It will be extremely difficult for me later to do indexing with this kind of structure.

**My soln. to problem:** So, I added this line `ranges=ranges_ndarray.tolist()`  after `ranges_ndarray`

**My soln. works lil but not how I want:** Now, the function returns `[0, 5]` which is good. But just in 2 time calling I see that the append is doing like `[0, 5, [0, 5]]`. This is also wrong for me as I want the output after append to be like `[[0, 5], [0, 5], ...]`

Can anyone suggest how to deal with this and get the output like `[[0, 5], [0, 5], ...]` . I am out of idea on how to simultaneously deal with myfunction and the append output to produce the form I want.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going wrong with this. My first call to the myfunction was `nos_indices=myfunction(some argument)` and then a for loop that keeps appending to this nos_indices. So, the first call gives `[0, 5]` which is ok but when called second time using the `nos_indices.append( myfunction(some argument))`, it caused to output to be `[0, 5, [0, 5]]`. Hence, to get [[0, 5], [0, 5], ...] I changed the first call as below.

```
nos_indices=myfunction(some argument)  #THIS IS REPLACED BY NEXT TWO LINES

nos_indices=[]
nos_indices.append(myfunction(some argument))
#then the for loop and subsequent append code as in question
```

This change keeps the first `[0, 5]` intact even after second call and corresponding append thus giving me `[[0, 5], [0, 5]]`